# How to choose server name when creating Knowledge Base when it's empty?

Tags: genexus

During my GeneXus installation, there was error in installing Microsoft SQL Server (GeneXus provided installer for 2014 version x86 requiring some WOW64, but my PC is Windows 10 x64).

Anyway, I've tried creating a KB and the GeneXus Trial IDE doesn't auto fill the 'Server Name' field. When I click `<Browse for more...>` I get an empty list.

[image: IDE]

Then I've tried putting anything, but the IDE fails to connect to the server.

Then I've tried installing Microsoft SQL Server 2019 for Windows 10, but I didn't install all features, and it didn't change anything.

Anything I could be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have [GeneXus 16 Requirements](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?30900,GeneXus%2016%20hardware%20and%20software%20requirements).
I recommend you to install SQL 2017 Express and SQL 2017 Management

Let me know how it goes

Comment: Thanks, I've instead tried rerunning SQL Server 2019 installer and added an extra feature, 'Database Engine Services', then finally the GeneXus IDE detected the server.